# Can't delete a non-empty subfolder inside project directory when node.js server is running

Tags: node.js, express

I am using 'fs-extra' module to remove a non-empty folder inside my project like this `fs.remove(filepath)` . The code runs and the folder is still there. After that i tried to delete the folder from windows explorer but i got a permission error. I think `fs.remove()` can't delete it because of permission related business and i am not sure why i would even need permission in the first place as i am the owner/admin.I can, however, delete the folder after i delete the files inside it though fs-extra is supposed to do that for me. One more thing that i noticed is that when i stop the node.js server only then can i delete the folder and there are no errors. Any pointers ?

Comment: What is the content of your folder ?

Comment: Its just an image in a sub folder. Book-->Cover-->cover.jpeg